# some elements in list of return values are undefine

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm working with a matrix, I'm try to get the file and column according with the value in other matrix

the matrix of values is :

```vb
matriz = [ 
        '1' '2' '3'; 
        '4' '5' '6'; 
        '7' '8' '9'; 
        '10' '11' '12' 
];
```

I've create a method , it's should return the file and column.

```vb
function  coordenada=getCoordenadas( casilla  )
contador =0;

for fila=1:4
     for columna=1:3
        contador = contador +1;
        if ( contador == casilla )
             x=fila;
             y=columna;
             cordenada = struct( 'x',fila,'y',columna );
             return 
        end %end if
     end    %end for columna
end%end for fila    
cordenada = struct( 'x',-1,'y',-1);

end
```

If I'm to use the function getCoordenadas( 1 );
but I get the mistake

***"warning: getCoordenadas: some elements in list of return values are undefine
d"***

What is the trouble, how to fix it's ?

Thask!!.

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns a variable named `coordenada` (two "o"s), but you're assigning a return value to another variable called `cordenada` (one "o").

Make these two variables have the same name to correct the error.

Comment: Did this answer help? Please consider accepting this answer if so.